# Implementing Sage Intacct API via Postman

Tags: request, receipt, postman-pre-request-script, purchase-order, intacct

I would like to get the invoice link from the purchase order implementing Sage Intacct API via Postman.

I suppose it can be done by following sequences(or by only one api request? not sure about this).

1. Order a purchase
2. Create a purchase receipt
3. Get an invoice link from it

Please refer to this API document (https://developer.intacct.com/api).

i.e. This is the body of a request to create a purchase transaction.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<request>
  <control>
    <senderid>{{sender_id}}</senderid>
    <password>{{sender_password}}</password>
    <controlid>{{$timestamp}}</controlid>
    <uniqueid>false</uniqueid>
    <dtdversion>3.0</dtdversion>
    <includewhitespace>false</includewhitespace>
  </control>
  <operation>
    <authentication>
      <sessionid>{{temp_session_id}}</sessionid>
    </authentication>
    <content>
      <function controlid="{{$guid}}">
        <create_potransaction>
          <transactiontype>Purchase Requisition</transactiontype>
          <datecreated>
            <year>2013</year>
            <month>6</month>
            <day>19</day>
          </datecreated>
          <vendorid>1001</vendorid>
          <referenceno>1234</referenceno>
          <vendordocno>vendordocno001</vendordocno>
          <datedue>
            <year>2013</year>
            <month>6</month>
            <day>20</day>
          </datedue>
          <payto>
            <contactname>Jameson Company</contactname>
          </payto>
          <exchratetype>Intacct Daily Rate</exchratetype>
          <customfields/>
          <potransitems>
            <potransitem>
              <itemid>75300GL</itemid>
              <quantity>100</quantity>
              <unit>Each</unit>
              <price>1</price>
              <locationid>MGMT-US</locationid>
              <departmentid>IT</departmentid>
            </potransitem>
          </potransitems>
        </create_potransaction>
      </function>
    </content>
  </operation>
</request>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the Postman collection file (API) from the developer docs.
And then just refer to Purchasing/Purchasing Transactions/Create Transaction (Legacy).
You can change the body (SOAP) content.
I'm sure you can manage it.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is helpful. We can create an invoice directly or from purchase order using 
 `<transactiontype>Vendor Invoice</transactiontype>`.

Comment: Nice detection.